# "lsof" command can not return files being opened by kwrite

Tags: linux, shell

The linux command "lsof" returns files that are being accessed,
I tried this in my shell with one file opened with vi and another opened with kwrite and then it returned and got the process of vi but no the process of kwrite , as below

[image: Image of commands on my shell]

```
[linux@localhost shell_ex]$ lsof +d .
COMMAND  PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF   NODE NAME
bash    3458 linux  cwd    DIR  253,2       50 953101 .
bash    3747 linux  cwd    DIR  253,2       50 953101 .
vim     3793 linux  cwd    DIR  253,2       50 953101 .
vim     3793 linux    4u   REG  253,2    12288 953102 ./.1.txt.swp
kwrite  3912 linux  cwd    DIR  253,2       50 953101 .
lsof    3914 linux  cwd    DIR  253,2       50 953101 .
lsof    3915 linux  cwd    DIR  253,2       50 953101 .
```

Here I got PID 3793 openning 1.txt and no PID that access 2.txt

Comment: `kwrite` probably doesn't hold the file descriptor open, so the file will show up only while it's actively being loaded or actively being saved. Nothing about this implies that `lsof` is doing anything wrong, or that there's anything that needs to be, should be, or *can be* fixed.

Comment: BTW, inasmuch as this is a question about using a piece of software as opposed to *writing* software, it's probably a better fit for [unix.se].

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question. I suggest deleting it and posting on [unix.se], or you can flag it and ask a moderator to migrate it.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 3):

`lsof` shows currently existing file descriptors (also called file handles, or abbreviated fd).
When you open a file with an editor (here vim or kwrite), they create a file descriptor to open the file, read the content, and close the file descriptor again.
As you can see in the output of lsof, neither editor has an open handle.
Once you save the file, the file is opened again (creating a new filedescriptor), the content is written and it the file descriptor is closed.

You can always list the currently existing file descriptors for a process in `/proc/<pid>/fd`.

The one file descriptor that you see for vim is not `1.txt`, but `.1.txt.swp`, but the [vim swap file](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/177/what-is-the-purpose-of-swap-files), where every change is written directly, so you can recover your changes if vim crashes (or your terminal closes) before you can save the file.